# XSD for complex XML structure

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation

I have a rather complex XML structure I am trying to validate and I can't seem to come up with a XSD structure that would allow me to express the following:

```
<foo fooAttribute1="..." fooAttribute2="..." ...>
  <bar1 id="1" ... />
  <bar1 id="2" ... />
  <bar2 id="1" ... />
  <bar2 id="2" ... />
  <![MyFormattedTextGoesHere[foo text goes here]]>
</foo>
```

So, I want to have a `foo` which *can* contain

- attributes
- 0..* `bar1` elements
- 0..* `bar2` elements
- *formatted* text (e.g. starting with `<![MyFormattedTextGoesHere[` and ending with `]]>`

On a related note: can I also validate attribute *values* like so: 
`<xml someAttribute=$... />` (has to start with a `$`)?

What I currently have is

```
<xs:element name="foo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="bar1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute name="id" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:attribute name="..." form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="bar2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute name="id" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:attribute name="..." form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="fooAttribute1" form="unqualified" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="fooAttribute2" form="unqualified" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="..." form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
    <!-- accept/validate text here? -->
  </xs:complexType>
  <!-- or here? -->
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Edited my question to show my current XSD structure. I tried to add simpleContent but couldn't mix it with the child elements `bar1`, `bar2`, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML above is not well-formed because of `<!` followed by general text. What is meant here may be a CDATA section, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo fooAttribute1="$..." fooAttribute2="..." >
   <bar1 id="1" />
   <bar1 id="2" />
   <bar2 id="1" />
   <bar2 id="2" />
   <![CDATA[MyFormattedTextGoesHere[foo text goes here]]>
</foo>
```

A good starting point for a schema against which the above XML is valid is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:simpleType name="beginswithdollar">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\$.*"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="foo">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="bar1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence/>
                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="bar2"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence/>
                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="fooAttribute1" type="beginswithdollar"/>
            <xs:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

A few things are not supported by XML Schema though:

- Whether text is in CDATA sections or not is not visible by XML Schema. CDATA sections are used to avoid escaping special characters.
- Complex types can be mixed-content or not. If mixed-content, it can not be controlled where the text appears or what its type is: it could also appear before or between `bar*` elements.
- Attributes can be allowed with no restriction with `xs:anyAttribute`, but it is not possible to restrict their type in general. In the above schema, for example, the attribute `fooAttribute1` must start with a dollar, while any other attributes are allowed with no restriction.

If XML Schema 1.1 is supported, there is also the `assert` feature that allows to express user-defined constraints. This may be a way to further restrict validity of instances in a tailored way beyond what other XML Schema components can do.

Comment: Thanks so far; one more question, though: Is there a way to check if there is a CDATA section present?

Comment: @vonludi No, as far as XSD is concerned it is irrelevant whether the text is in a CDATA section or not (just as it is irrelevant if `E` is written as `&#x45;`)